# The $ajax http post method does not work with Firefox, but with safari and chrome instead

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, firefox

Can someone explain why this function does not work in firefox?
At first I thought it was a problem of form submission. So I reduced the code to the one performed at runtime function. Same problem with firefox: internal 500 server error. Thank you for your time.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
var urls;
urls = "http://server/api/v1/update/discipline";
var data = {"id": "702","disciplinaNome":"John Doe 4"}   
$.ajax({
url: urls,
type: "POST",
data: data,
contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",    
success: function(responseData, textStatus, jqXHR) {
alert("data edited")
console.log("Data: " + responseData + "\nStatus: " + textStatus);
//if success close modal and reload ajax table
reload_table();
},
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
console.log("Data Error: " + errorThrown + "\nStatus: " + textStatus);
//  alert('Error update data');
}
});
});

 </script>
```

Firefox F5:
[image][image][image]
CHROME F5
[image]

Comment: Why are you focusing on the client side code? You have an internal **server** error. Look at the error reporting on the server to find out what is wrong, then worry about changing the client to fix it.

Comment: @Quentin Since it's working in some clients but not the others, perhaps the client-side code is treated differently before being sent off to the server. At least, that's my initial thought.

Comment: But why with safari and firefox work well? if the problem is on the server all three browser must be fail. or not?

Comment: I would try to verify the data and the requests first, using Postman or something similar, from various browser, to see if the problem persists. Checking content types, payloads etc.

Comment: @sundsx — Presumably there is *something* different about the requests, but if you look at the server error logs you should get more of a clue about what to look for in order to work out which differences are significant.

Comment: @quentin so i must look at apache log? ok after i will replay

Comment: For major info, my restfull api are conform with Curl for all Crud operation.

Comment: @quentin in apache log i can see what happen. So if i try with Chrome or safari the log goes empty. If i try with FF i get:

[Fri Feb 05 15:08:41 2016] [warn] [client 93.63.155.226] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 near "WHERE": syntax error' in /var/www/vhosts/server/httpdocs/api/v1/update/api.php:167".